# Pad punctuation and other non alphanumeric characters with space

Tags: regex, regexp-replace, postgresql-9.6

I would like to replace all non alphanumeric characters (like commas) with space || this_character || space.
So after executing the query:

```
SELECT 'the quick, brown, fox jumps over the lazy dog'
```

I would like to get the following output:

```
the quick , brown , fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Comment: What if there is a comma at the start of the string? Should a space be inserted before it?

Comment: yes, in every case

Comment: Just not when there is already a space, like in the example after a comma? Or do you want a second space to be inserted then?

Comment: without a difference really, because the sentence goes after that through another function for which there is no difference if there is one or more spaces (it's using \\s+ anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this to insert a space before and after any non-alphanumerical character (non-white space), independent on whether there is already a space in that position:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('the quick, brown, fox jumps over the lazy dog', 
                      E'[^\\w\\s]', E' \\& ', 'g')
```